# Checkbox in codeigniter

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Here i am using Bootstrap for checkbox ... While i am click checkbox it checked but in the bootstrap design it was not shown ...

my Code:

```
<label for="success" class="btn btn-success">Success <input type="checkbox" value="" id="success" class="badgebox"><span class="badge">&check;</span></label>
```

My css code:

```
<style>

  /* Hiding the checkbox, but allowing it to be focused */
.badgebox
{
    opacity: 0;
}

.badgebox + .badge
{
    /* Move the check mark away when unchecked */
    text-indent: -999999px;
    /* Makes the badge's width stay the same checked and unchecked */
  width: 27px;
}

.badgebox:focus + .badge
{
    /* Set something to make the badge looks focused */
    /* This really depends on the application, in my case it was: */

    /* Adding a light border */
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px;
    /* Taking the difference out of the padding */
}

.badgebox:checked + .badge
{
    /* Move the check mark back when checked */
  text-indent: 0;
}</style>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem briefly. because I've checked your code and it's running pretty good. If possible then tell Us that what you are getting and what you want to get.

Comment: That's working bro ... but we are using dynamic data means whay we have to do.. My questions are

Comment: 1.id='checkbox-1' How to use this ....     2. How to select Multiple checkboxes in form  3. How to send the selected row values into database ...

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
public function workout()
    {

        if($this->input->post())
        {
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->input->post()); 

            exit();
        }

        $this->load->view('workout');
    }
```

view file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css">

.sr-only { 
opacity: 0;
float: right;

}
input[type='checkbox'].tags-checkbox:checked + label > i:first-of-type,
input[type='checkbox'].tags-checkbox + label > i:last-of-type{
    display: none;
}
input[type='checkbox'].tags-checkbox:checked + label > i:last-of-type{
    display: inline-block;
}




</style>

<form name="form" id="form" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/workout" method="post" >

Vehicles you have.?
<br /><br />

<div><span class='label-content'> I have a car</span>
    <input name="optionshaving[]" type='checkbox' id='checkbox-1' value="bike"  class='tags-checkbox sr-only'/>
    <label for='checkbox-1'>
        <i >&#x2717;</i>
        <i >&check;</i>
    </label>
</div>

<div><span class='label-content'> I have a bike</span>
    <input name="optionshaving[]" type='checkbox' value="car" id='checkbox-2' class='tags-checkbox sr-only'/>
    <label for='checkbox-2'>
        <i >&#x2717;</i>
        <i >&check;</i>
    </label>
</div>


<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />

</form>



</body>
</html>
```

output is

```
Array
(
    [optionshaving] => Array
        (
            [0] => bike
            [1] => car
        )

    [submit] => submit
)
```

Comment: That's working bro ... but we are using dynamic data means whay we have to do ....

Comment: 2. How to select Multiple checkboxes in form

Comment: iam going to post a new answer pls check it.

Comment: Thanks brother but am asking is if am getting one id value means i will take data from database with that .... But here We are Getting array only ... With this array I have to take all the row of particular Id value ... how to do